# Modal scroll not working properly only on safari browser

Tags: css, styles, cascading

I have used modal in my react.js website. But it's scroll event not working properly in safari browser. I have checked it all other browsers, It's working properly. In Safari when we scroll down it's merged all text fields. 
I have given my modal following CSS properties.

```
  position: fixed;
  top: 64px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 99;
  background: #fff;
```

I have tried to solve this issue to changing overflow property value, but nothing happens.
Any help on this issue is appreciable.
Thank you.